# How to increase axios speed?

Tags: reactjs, http, django-rest-framework, react-redux, axios

Because I'm new to using axios so I usually have a trouble in using it. Specifically, I'm making a `react-infinite-scroll` feature now, but when I compare its speed with other site, my post(`react-infinite-scroll` feature) is gonna be shown slowly a little. Then I'm thinking this problem is caused by 2 reasons
1. I'm not using `axios` properly
2. There is a thing makes `axios` speed urgrade, but I'm not using it
Here's my code, please give me some advice to increase my http request speed.

Thank you for reading my question!

```
class MainPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/question")
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                AnswerPostMultiList: res.data
            })
          }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    state = {
        AnswerPostMultiList : []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    handleScroll = () => {

        console.log("scroll is executing")

        const { innerHeight } = window;
        const { scrollHeight } = document.body;

        const scrollTop =
          (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) ||
          document.body.scrollTop;

        if (scrollHeight - innerHeight - scrollTop < 1000 && !this.props.isLoading["isLoading"]) {
          this.props.onIsLoading() #To prevent this code from calling back continuously, change the value of this.props.isLoading["isLoading"] to false 

              axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/question")
              .then(res => {

              this.setState({
                  AnswerPostMultiList: this.state.AnswerPostMultiList.concat(res.data)
              })
              this.props.onIsLoading() #change the value of this.props.isLoading["isLoading"] to true 
            }
          )
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
          })
        }
      };

    render() {
        return(
            <>

                <PageHeader />
                <div className="find_members">
                { this.state.AnswerPostMultiList.map((answerpost,index) => {
                    return <AnswerPostMulti question={answerpost.question_text} q_owner={answerpost.question_owner} answer={answerpost.answer_image} a_owner={answerpost.answer_owner} key={index} />
                  })
                }
                </div>

            </>
        )
    }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onIsLoading: () => {
        dispatch(isLoadingActions.isLoading())
    }
  })

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      isLoading: state.isLoading
  })


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage)
```

Comment: You can check how requests perform in devtools Network tab. Nobody but you can do this. You could try to debounce `handleScroll` for starters.

Comment: @estus Thanks for your reply, yes! I'm gonna try everything to solve it by myself! however, if I try everything, but it's not gonna work, Could I get some even simple advice from you..?

Comment: Try to search for 'react scroll debounce' here on SO, there's a lot of working examples. If something you try doesn't work for you, consider reasking the question and addressing the problem directly. More specific questions have better chances to get a proper answer.

Comment: @estus OK I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The best place to call a **axios API calls** is at **componentDidMount(){}**.
The Application loading process will be in this order skeleton->Initial rendering->later componentDidMount method is called. So here your app skeleton will be loaded and after that you can fetch data and use it to your app skeleton.

```
componentDidMount() {
         axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/question")
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                AnswerPostMultiList: res.data
            })
          }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
```